# How to run the mule job based on an event

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

i want to run my mule flow only when the file arrives at a particular path.How to do that.
since event wait is not there in mulesoft, i thought of running the job every 30 minutes .So that it check the file and run.
But the problem here is, it is not necessary , that the file will be available at every 30 min. when the file is not available , it should not throw any error also.
Note: Job will be running once a month. 
Suggestions needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is exactly On New Or Updated File Connector with schedule based on the **cron** expression to run every month.
[image]